# Write JavaScript variable on HTML Body

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Reverse Geocoding</title>
        <link
        href="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder;

            var variablejs;

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            var input = "41.021355,-96.020508";
            var latlngStr = input.split(",", 2);
            var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
            var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            geocoder.geocode({
                'latLng': latlng
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (results[0]) {
                        variablejs = results[0].formatted_address; * * //document.write(variablejs); Not working**
                        *
                        //window.location.href = "http://localhost/test2.php?ad="+ variablejs; Working*
                    } else {
                        alert("No results found");
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                }
            }); * * document.write(variablejs); * * //writes undefined variable (not working)
        </script>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

The section (**//document.write(variablejs); Not working**), won't write the variable "variablejs", but when I use the method (**//window.location.href = "http://localhost/test2.php?ad="+ variablejs; Working**), it will write the url and forward the page passing the variable as a parameter. What I want to do is print that variable in the body of the same HTML. 
I tried to initialize first the variable then write into the Body but It looks like that section is not accessible like a global variable or something like that. Please help.

Comment: change var variablejs; to var variablejs=""; and you should be good to go

Comment: Why not putting in the body something like this: <div id="output"></div>, and change document.write(something) to document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = something;?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the document is loaded, you can't use `document.write` without overwriting everything. You will need to manipulate the DOM, e.g. `document.body.innerText=variablejs;`. But I'd recommend

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(variablejs));
document.body.appendChild(d);
```

Comment: Can you point me, where `onload` event is triggered before using `document.write()` in OP's code?

Comment: Nowhere, but I suppose geocoder.geocode(params, callback) uses a XMLHttpRequest - usually slower than DOMready.

Comment: Wow... This explains also why OP gets "undefined variable"-error at last line.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning value to variablejs in the callback function you're passing to geocoder.geocode(). This means that you're trying to access and write it before the callback has been called and therefore you will not see any value set yet.

Debugging with Firebug or similar will help in these cases.

Also you can't use docuemnt.write like that after the document has been loaded, you'll need to do some DOM-manipulation instead.